# In dayJs, disable date overflow without using strict format

Tags: javascript, date, dayjs

Using dayJs, i want to disable overflow e.g :

```
-> 32-12-2023 16:00 //invalid with format dd-mm-yyyy HH:ss
```

We can do this using strict mode = true :

```
dayjs(date, format, true);
```

But in this case, this date becomes invalid :

```
-> 3-12-2023 16:00 //invalid
```

Can I keep a flexible format while disabling overflow ?

Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The params format can be an array which contains more format.

```js
dayjs(date, ['dd-mm-yyyy HH:ss', 'd-mm-yyyy HH:ss'], true);
```

Answer (score 0):

As @moon said, you can include multiple parse formats as an array. The issue is that with strict parsing, you have to include all combinations of two digit day and month formats, e.g.

```js
dayjs.extend(dayjs_plugin_customParseFormat);

let formats = [
  'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm',
  'D-MM-YYYY HH:mm',
  'DD-M-YYYY HH:mm',
  'D-M-YYYY HH:mm'
];

['01-05-2023 12:00',
 '1-05-2023 12:00',
 '01-5-2023 12:00',
 '1-5-2023 12:00',
 '51-05-2023 12:00', // Out of bounds day
 '01-25-2023 12:00'  // Out of bounds month
].forEach(s => 
   console.log(s + ' -> ' + dayjs(s, formats, true).format('DD-MMM-YYYY'))
);
```

```html
<!-- load dayjs -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/dayjs.min.js"></script>
<!-- load plugin -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/plugin/customParseFormat.js"></script>
```

PS I used this answer to test running plugins from a CDN in the SO snippet editor (in this case, *customPasrseFormat*). It works with [cdn.jsdelivr.net](https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/loading-into-browser) at least. :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was wondering if there is a way to do that without having to specify multiple formats, aiming to have a more concise and cleaner code. Especially since the formats are in my case provided by the backend.

Comment: @painpita—one option is for parsers to support wild cards so "?D" meant either "D" or "DD". Alternatively, if you could specify strict parsing for format and values separately, so non–strict parsing to allow "D" or "DD" but strict for values to prevent out of range values.